# Extra percent sign appears in echo bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, echo

I've got the following script below which is supposed to demo CPU utilization:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Color declarations
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
LIGHTBLUE='\033[1;34m'
LIGHTGREEN='\033[1;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

a=1
b=3
end=$((SECONDS+120))

echo "CPU Utilization:"
echo "1%"

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ] ; do

        echo -e "${GREEN}\e[1A$((a+RANDOM%(b-a))).$((RANDOM%99))%${NC}"

        sleep 1

done
```

For some reason, when the percentage is echoed out, two percent signs appear instead of the last digit of the number and a percent sign. For example, the output is sometimes 2.7%% instead of 2.72%. Everything works fine when I take the percent sign away, but even if I include a space between the percent sign and the random number generation, the percent sign still appears occasionally. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Specifically, the issue is with the percent sign here:

```
echo -e "${GREEN}\e[1A$((a+RANDOM%(b-a))).$((RANDOM%99))%${NC}"
                                                        ^
```

Comment: Yes -- what's it doing there to begin with?? It's not within an arithmetic operator and you are certainly not using `printf` so introducing a format specifier is not relevant??

Comment: Also note: `\033[K` provides `"Erase to end of line"` which can also be useful in these cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is overwriting what was already there, but a percentage sign may be left over that doesn’t get overwritten. If the previous result was

```
2.33%
```

and this time you’re writing

```
2.7%
```

in the same space, it only overwrites the first four characters, so the previous percent character remains. So you should add a space, but *after* the percent character.

Comment: Ah, that makes a ton of sense. Perhaps it's because of how I wrote it, but is there a way to always output a zero so that the number won't be either 2.7 and 2.70 and will just be 2.70?

Comment: `printf '%0.2f' 2.7` will emit `2.70`; similarly, you can use `printf -v pct_str '%0.2f' 2.7` to put `2.70` in the variable named `pct_str` without the performance overhead involved in command substitution.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, can I use `${GREEN}` and `${NC}` with printf? I tried `printf '%0.2f%s' "$((a+RANDOM%(b-a))).$((RANDOM%99))" "${NC}"` but it output `\033[0m`, which makes sense, but do you know a way to make the color work with `printf` like you can with `echo -e`?